# Global variables vanish in WordPress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, global-variables

I'm writing a WordPress plugin. I want to display a custom message after a post is saved. This message will depend on the outcome of function called when the post is saved.

Here's my code:

```
add_action('save_post', 'my_save_post_function');
function my_save_post_function() {
  global $msg;
  $msg = "Foo bar";
  ...
}

add_filter('post_updated_messages', 'my_post_updated_messages_function');
function my_post_updated_messages_function($messages) {
  global $msg;
  $messages["post"][1] = $msg; // !! $msg is undefined !!
  ...
}
```

Why is `$msg` undefined?

Is there any way I can get a result out of a `save_post` action? I've tried all sorts of tricks. Even the `$_POST` data seems to have been blown away by the time admin messages are shown.

Comment: global is generally bad practice, parse the variables though the functions

Comment: this looks like flash messages, so why not use sessions for this? I know wp doesn't use sessions, but you can start the session in your plugin and go from there. Also, in the way you did your code, is really really bad...it really depends on the order your functions are called and if they are called in the same execution cycle.

Comment: [Have a read of this](http://betterwp.net/8-using-global-variables-in-wordpress/), the last section of the article explains how to achieve what you want.

Comment: @Dagon, I hate using globals too for this but I can't pass the variables through the functions. The output of `my_save_post_function` depends on the value of `$_POST` and `$_POST` has vanished (!?) when `my_post_updated_messages_function` get called. I can't determine what the outcome was or should have been by the time `my_post_updated_messages_function` get called. Hence, the cruddy globals. I'll give sessions a go. Event if that's just another way around `globals`, it's one I hadn't thought of. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried session  ? i think your problem will be fixed .

take a look at :

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: Ugh. Horrible solution (not you're fault!) but it does the job. Thanks!